# Actualizar datagridview luego de un insert

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-forms, datagridview

Estoy intentando actualizar un `DataGridView` cuando se realiza un `insert` pero no me ha salido.

**Clase Conexión:**

```
//método para cargar el datagridview
        public DataTable Query()
        {
            DataTable datos = new DataTable();//creamos un DataTable
            using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();//abrimos la conexión
                    datos.AcceptChanges();
                    String consulta = "SELECT nombre FROM Clientes";//creamos un string con la consulta a sql
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(consulta, con);//cremaos un comando al cual le pasamos las variables que serían la consulta y la conexión para que las ejecute
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);//este se encarga de inicializar el command
                    da.Fill(datos);//aquí se agergan o actualizan las fila
                    con.Close();//cerramos al conexión
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            return datos;
        }
```

**En el Form1.cs:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Es aquí donde vamos a cargar el dtg
            //creamos bien hermoso el dataset
            ds = new DataSet();

            //acá agregamos la carga de la consulta al dtg
            ds.Tables.Add(conexionSQL.Query());

            //establecemos el origen de los datos
            dtgClientes.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        }
```

Y en el botón donde inserto el registro hago esto:

```
private void btnInsertar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Persona p = new Persona();
            ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
            string nombre = txtNombre.Text;
            string apellido = txtApellido.Text;
            string mail = txtEmail.Text;
            long tel = Convert.ToInt64(txtTelefono.Text);
            bool idBorrado = false;

            p = new Persona(nombre, apellido, mail, tel, idBorrado);

            sql.insert(p);

            dtgClientes.Update();
            dtgClientes.Refresh();
        }
```

Pero, no se actualiza el `DataGridView` luego del `insert`, ¿Alguna posible solución? Aclaro que los **textbox-botón-datagridview** están en el mismo `Form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te fijaste si se actualizaron los datos en el SQL? Porque lo que puede estar pasando es que los datos si se actualicen en el SQL, pero no en la vista, ya el `DataGridView` sigue teniendo como referencia los datos que le pasaste en el `Form1_Load`.
Lo que te recomiendo es hacer lo mismo que hiciste en el `Form1_Load` después de insertar el dato. La forma correcta es hacer una función que por ejemplo se llame `ActualizarDGV()`

Básicamente te quedaría algo así:

Form_load()

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Es aquí donde vamos a cargar el dtg
    ActualizarDGV()
}
```

ActualizarDGV()

```
private void ActualizarDGV()
{
     //creamos bien hermoso el dataset
     ds = new DataSet();

     //acá agregamos la carga de la consulta al dtg
     ds.Tables.Add(conexionSQL.Query());

     //establecemos el origen de los datos
     dtgClientes.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Y por último le agregas al final del código del botón para que se actualice, y yo creo que ya estaría!

```
private void btnInsertar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Persona p = new Persona();
        ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
        string nombre = txtNombre.Text;
        string apellido = txtApellido.Text;
        string mail = txtEmail.Text;
        long tel = Convert.ToInt64(txtTelefono.Text);
        bool idBorrado = false;

        p = new Persona(nombre, apellido, mail, tel, idBorrado);

        sql.insert(p);

        ActualizarDGV()
    }
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Sí, si hacía el insert y me sirvió tu respuesta. Gracias :)